# Document root of my Mediatemple Gridserver to access public folder of Laravel 4

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, mediatemple

I am trying to set up my gridserver to point to my public folder when i go to my domain: example.com should point to example.com/public.

I have tried a few things in .htaccess, but they have failed.  Do you have any idea of how to do this?  Thank you.

Also, if you know how to run php artisan commands from the terminal, but pointing them at my FTP to get at my project on my gridserver.

Comment: You may need to ask their support. THe best I could find after some googling was using symlinks. See [here](https://forum.mediatemple.net/topic/2664-possible-to-change-the-document-root/) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your `public` folder to `html` (as is (gs) convention) and then update the path to the public folder in `bootstrap/paths.php`.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe it was this simple!  I've been messing with symlinks, htaccess, all that jazz...this accomplished all of that.  You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think symbolic links work fine and should be more maintainable when deploying the app on MT

You can create a symbolic link by going into the MT's /html folder.

ln -s /home/000000/domains/some.domain.com/public/index.php index.php

Similary for CSS or JS folders you might have